# PHP formatting data string to MySQL date format

Tags: php, date

I have this string I'm getting from the GUI: 09/22/2012  (mm/dd/yyyy).

I want to format it to:

```
date("Y-m-d");  //(the MySQL DATE format )
```

What should be the right PHP date function parameters to do so?

Comment: What do you mean by `what shell the php` ???

Comment: @Baba I think he means "What should be the right parameters for the php date function" ("shell" is probably a typo for "shall").

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", "09/22/2012");
echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
```

Output

```
2012-09-22
```

Comment: This solution is better than the other one given.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the following to get the MySQL date format.

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('09/22/2012'));
// Output: 2012-09-22
```

Hope that helps.